# Adding property to URL config

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to modify a request header via my interceptor, however when I set the content type of a request the request function stops without any error.

The function stops at the line `config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`

I'm thinking it's because the property 'Content-Type' doesn't exist on the object header but i'm pretty sure it's possible to add properties to an object like this in js.

```
const requestLogin = async (loginDTO) => {
        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(loginDTO)
        };
        return await fetch(`${baseURL}/Account/Login`, requestOptions);
    }

request: function (url, config) {
            // Modify the url or config here
            if (!config) return;
            config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            return [url, config];
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `config.headers['Content-Type']` if `config.headers` is already an object. If it is not then you get a TypeError.

Try to write a more strict guard:

```js
if (!config || !config.headers || typeof config.headers !== 'object') return;
config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
return [url, config];
```